# Strange particle omission area in render (Internal)

Tags: rendering, blender-internal-render-engine, particles

I'm trying to create a scene to render a skydome for a game in Blender Internal, and this strange rendering effect started occurring:
[image: Render result]

As you can see, there's a weird half-square on both sides of the image that's curved as though against the camera lens, where the cloud particles are completely cut out and there's a difference in colour in the World background. It also looks like there's a thin beam of light on the bottom of the squares which connects horizontally to each other.

The camera has a Field Of View of 90 degrees and the image output ratio is 1:1 (500x500 pixels). Mist is being used.

This is really bizarre and I've got no idea how to fix it or even what to describe it as. Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the mist was actually affecting the particle emission volume, so the corners were being affected more by the mist and getting culled out closer towards the vertices. I solved this by just making it a perfect cube and adding power 4 subdivision surface. Not sure why mist affects an invisible particle volume in the first place, but it's for Internal so I guess I can't really complain... :P